# Loading Scene From Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-storyboard

I am trying to launch a view controller that I created in my storyboard using the code below, but I get a `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` and a `Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT` on the first line of my app delegate file.

```
func PostBtnAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"PostView")
    self.present(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

I set the custom class to `PostViewController` and I set the storyboard ID to `PostView`.

Loading the scene using this code below launches a view, but gives me a black screen.

```
func PostBtnAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let secondViewController:PostViewController = PostViewController()
    self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using? Check whether `libc++abi.dylib` is available in build phase of the project

Comment: Check, is Main.storyboard connected to your target. And check, that you exactly set the storyboard ID "PostView". In second case you load PostViewController from code, not from storyboard, thats why it is clear. If you load viewcontroller from the same storyboard, try to replace to 'let viewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier...`

Comment: add `print(storyboard)` and `print(viewController)` and check (or add breakpoint and check step by step)

Comment: Both of the things you told me to check are correct. I replaced the code as you said, but I got an error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value`

Comment: Class with this function (PostBtnAction) launched from Main.storyboard? What superclass of class PostViewController? By the way, correct name of function should be postBtnAction. Did you try 'print(storyboard)'? What did you get?

Comment: Turns out deleting the outlets I had and adding them back fixed it.